# Did something change in the behavior of blocking users' votes if they don't have sufficient rep to vote?

Tags: discussion, voting

I've just noticed that if you try to vote without having a privilege to vote, you're greeted with such message:

> [image: Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 125 reputation, your votes will change the publicly-displayed post score.]

So, that's interesting. Does it mean that if I gain 125 (or 15, in case I'm upvoting not having 15 reps) rep on that site, my "suggested" vote goes public and until then it would be recorded as it's done with anon feedback?

And until this change, the votes weren't recorded as anonymous, or has the new message saying that it acts as feedback been added just to not upset users?

Comment: "my "suggested" vote goes public and until then it would be recorded as it's done with anon feedback" - I very much doubt this. The message likely means your *future* votes -- however, it's not too clear about that.

Comment: @hich Hm, maybe.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, it means you're not voting. You're leaving "feedback" — we track the nature of your vote, but don't alter the post score in response to it.

Once you earn 125 reputation, you can actually vote.

This was implemented to be more inline with the message given to anonymous users, who see:

[image]

(The previous message shown to low-rep logged-in users was a terse red error.)

The message has since been revised further, and now says something more like this:

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: And the feedback is actually recorded?

Comment: Yes, yes it is. You can even find it recorded in the data dump and SEDE within the PostFeedback table.

Comment: Just a bit of feedback: I like this feature, noticed it today. When it occurred for me it didn't feel like "computer says no" (like the previous message), it was much more "we do care what you think".

Comment: I'm confused with the wording of the new message. Does this mean that the "fake feedback votes" of logged-in non-vote-priveliged-users actually turn into "real vote" automatically once they reach required rep? If that's not the case, then maybe it should be "..., your ***new*** votes..."

Comment: What does "feedback" mean? I don't get what the point of this is.

Comment: [Example](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/702334) @Clonkex

Comment: Ok, but... what is the _point_ of this?

Comment: See what folks like/dislike when they can't vote.