# Change wording for banner displayed when user doesn't have enough rep to downvote

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, down-votes, new-users

Earlier today, I was on the site of a Stack Exchange community that I have joined, but don't yet have 125 reputation, so I can't downvote. I wasn't thinking about that when I tried to downvote an answer, and this banner was displayed:

[image: Downvote Banner]

I think the phrasing used in this banner is misleading and should be changed, for two reasons:

1. The phrase "publicly-displayed post score" implies that there is some kind of hidden score that the vote *does* count against. As far as I know, there is no such thing.
2. It makes it seem like the 125 rep requirement applies to all votes, when it should distinguish between rep requirements for upvotes and downvotes. A new user may be confused about why upvotes change the score, but downvotes don't.

I suggest something like the following:

> Thanks for the feedback! You may upvote posts, but downvoting requires 125 [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation).

If I remember correctly, the banner used to say something like this, so I believe the current phrasing is a fairly recent change (within the last few months). Unfortunately, I can't find a blog or meta post that mentions the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The phrase "publicly-displayed post score" implies that there is some
>   kind of hidden score that the vote does count against. As far as I
>   know, there is no such thing.

It is stored and used, in some, mysterious unicornical way.
You can read more here in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259591/230506) and comments.

> Q: And the feedback is actually recorded?
>   A: Yes, yes it is. You can even find it recorded in the data dump and
>   SEDE within the PostFeedback table.

The answer was by a Staff member.

> It makes it seem like the 125 rep requirement applies to all votes

Not really, it's pop-up message which applies to whatever you clicked.
Click upvote and you get a different message, click add comment and you get another, etc.

> A new user may be confused about why upvotes change the score, but
>   downvotes don't.

Possibly, but a new user can potentially be confused by a lot of things if they don't read welcome advice.
That doesn't mean we shouldn't make improvements where we can, but I think it's logical to get a specific message based on what you click on.

Comment: *There was an answer to this recently, am still trying to find it.* Hehe me too!

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Too slow ;)