# Message for upvotes is misleading

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, privileges, up-votes

I realized the other day on SciFi & Fantasy SE that the upvote message is misleading.  I had joined and asked a question, [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111750/can-weeping-angels-still-move-while-they-are-stone/) if you were wondering, and tried to upvote an answer.

It gave me a message saying that my upvotes would not be shown until I had 15 rep.

> [image: 15 rep notice]

Okay, I understand that.  Same with downvotes.  It makes sense not to allow voting privileges immediately.

But when I had ≥15 rep and could now upvote, I realized it didn't actually upvote the answer.  I understand that too, but I don't think it should tell me it was hidden when it didn't exist.

#### I propose we change the <15 rep upvote message to something less misleading.

For example:

*You need ≥15 rep to upvote answers/question/comments*

Just something less misleading.

**I understand that the attempted vote is tracked, I wish to change the message to say that.**

Note: I am asking to change that tooltip, not questioning what it does.

### Can a SE unicorn please help with this?

## UPDATE: The tooltip has been changed. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289795/311528).

Comment: Though wait, it's not really a dupe. I've asked why, and this is asking to change the tooltip. different things.

Comment: So, just related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259583/did-something-change-in-the-behavior-of-blocking-users-votes-if-they-dont-have

Comment: Given the related question, you should probably amend your suggestion to clarify instead that, while the upvote does count for *something*, it's not going to do anything more than it already did.

Comment: Why does the tooltip say 125 reputation?

Comment: @pyt downvote probably

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks for the image, I changed it to an upvote to make it more clear though.

Comment: No problem. I just copied it from the other post to make it clear for future viewers.

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept your answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## This has been updated.

The new message:

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

[image: image name here pls]

Comment: Just a heads up - I'm undeleting this answer. The difference between the old message and new is subtle but important - the new version says that the publicly displayed score is *not* changed even if you eventually have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: @AdamLear it's subtle, a bit too subtle IMHO, but I guess I see it.

Comment: I still think that this message is misleading. I have fallen into this trap. I put a lot of effort into choosing which posts to upvote on multiple SE sites where I had <15 reps and was recently surprised and annoyed to see on the TeX-LaTeX SE that they did not appear when I reached at least 15 reps there.
I think the message should say "(...) but _will never_ change the publicly displayed score." or "(...) are recorded _for moderators' information only and_ (...)". A user with low reputation, like I, doesn't suspect that this "recording" is for something he doesn't and will never care about.

Answer (score 38):

Indeed. The current message is very misleading and actually wrong. It makes you think the votes will be automatically applied, which they aren't.

To keep the 'we do something with your feedback' part of the message, my counterproposal is:

> Thanks for your feedback! You need ≥15 rep to upvote posts. We will remember your vote for analysis. Once you have earned enough reputation you can vote on this post again.

It makes clear that the vote casted doesn't do more than just get stored for analysis (through SEDE as Shog9 explained in the linked post).

Comment: I think that message isn't really concise enough.

Comment: I can agree on that. How would you shorten it and still make clear what their vote actually did?

Comment: Tried to remove some content. Hope it is better now @the

Comment: The problem is that there's a delicate balance between informationality and conciseness. Personally, I think the best would be a very concise message with link to further explanation.

Comment: I sympathize with the intent, but I'm not sure that explicitly calling it a vote makes this *less* misleading, particularly since there's currently no easily-obtainable record of these "votes" the way there is for real votes (consider that a user with 20 rep would be able to find all of the posts he'd upvoted in his profile, but would see anything "downvoted" suspiciously absent in spite of the claims that they are remembered). I suspect it'll be hard to avoid problems in a terse message without actually changing what anon feedback *does*...

Comment: Okay. Got that @shog9. Why is the feedback / vote message even shown? What was the reason for that?

Comment: As a way to make the basic mechanics of the system - earn rep to vote - a bit more discoverable.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I will change the accepted answer when the tooltip is changed and they post that here.

Comment: :/ looks like 100 more rep incoming

Comment: Sorry I can't help it. I would love to fix it myself...

Comment: You proposal was accepted

Answer (score 13):

Like how Patrick Hofman said, the message is very misleading and makes you think that your vote was counted after all. In fact, the vote doesn't show on the post but is taken into analysis. Actually, let's use that for the message.

The message:

> Thank you for your feedback! You need ≥15 rep for your votes to count on posts, but your feedback will be kept for analysis instead.

will do three things:

- Be short, simple and straight to-the-point
- Mentions that you need ≥15 rep to upvote
- Also mentions that the "vote" will be taken as feedback (as mentioned in first sentence in message) and will be sent and kept for analysis

In the meanwhile, this should be [should-be-completed-but-is-not](/questions/tagged/should-be-completed-but-is-not).

Comment: This is good, but what I am looking for is a [tag:status-accepted] tag and have it fixed by SE.

Comment: And sorry, but this is exactly what I didn't want, the `your vote to appear` message.  It isn't a vote at all, and it won't appear because it doesn't exist!

Comment: Well it is a vote, just one that doesn't appear on the post's vote count

Comment: No, that is the problem. It isn't.  It is tracked, but doesn't count for anything.

Comment: There... maybe changing vote to feedback will work this time

Comment: Yes! Exactly that.

Comment: You got the bounty. Still, I want a [tag:status-completed].