# Does it make sense to give upvotes before I have 15 reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, up-votes

**Short of the question:**  Does it do any good to provide an up-vote if you have less than 15 reputation points?  They are not displayed to help others identify answers that worked.  Do they show up after I gain 15 reputation points?

**Longer explanation**

I have multiple stackexchange accounts but I only have over 15 reputation points in the one I use most.  In that forum I am in the habit of giving up-votes when a question and/or answer has helped me, but I am not sure if it does any good elsewhere.  Because of my work situation up-voting is my best method of giving back to the community - taking time to monitor the site for opportunities to answer questions isn't appropriate, though I do attempt to contribute when, by chance, I see an opportunity.  I also rarely have a question that hasn't already been asked. Because of this my reputation grows very slowly.

So, when I find a question/answer in an Exchange forums where I have less than 15 reputation points it is frustrating to see the notification that my vote is counted but not posted; I wonder if my up-votes will ever contribute in any way.  Do I just wait until I have 15 reputation points to vote?  Or, when I reach that level in some distant future, will they suddenly start contributing, and help to guide later questioners to good answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you up vote with less than 15 rep (or down vote with less than 125), it is [recorded as feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285181/323179).

If you work hard to earn at least 200 rep on one site, then you will get the association bonus, which will give you +100 rep to all your accounts.

The easiest way to earn reputation **is** giving good answers and it's another way to give back to the community. In my experience, Stack Overflow is a hard site to gain rep on, but I got my association bonus from answering there. You might also want to check out all the [other sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) in the Stack Exchange network; there are so many and you'll surely find another site that interests you.

See [this help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) for more information on rep.

Comment: I know I am not supposed to say this, but Thanks!  I would up-vote you, but I only have 3 reputation points now.  I see that I have asked a duplicate question (and I agree), but I don't know how anyone found it based on the different question titles.   Thanks for pointing out the association bonus.