# Unrecord accidental vote on a site where I have less than 15 reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, privileges, post-feedback

I've accidentally voted on an answer on a site where I have less than 15 reputation. I wanted to undo it, but clicking it again just returns the same message that my vote was "recorded". Is there a way to undo this action before getting 15 reputation?

I think a feature to allow such users to undo it would be better, because someone can accidentally do what I did, and then forget about the question and therefore never undo their incorrect vote.

Comment: Did you upvote or accept an answer? You should have some time before your vote is locked, how long did it take for you to realize you 'misvoted'?

Comment: @Joachim I upvoted it. I realised i misvoted roughly 4 seconds after I did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't really matter.  It's [taken into account for statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285181/once-i-reach-15-reputation-will-my-old-votes-be-taken-into-account), but doesn't really affect reputation if you have less than 15 reputation.

As far as I know the statistics are not used for anything, so it's literally a record in a database and nothing else. It also won't be 'converted' into real votes which count for post score and reputation once you hit the reputation levels to upvote and downvote.

Comment: See also: [Plyushkin's disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsive_hoarding) (compulsive hording) :P