How does downvote feedback work?
If you don't have the necessary reputation to downvote something on a given site, it'll say:

Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 125 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Does the recorded feedback change how much the question is seen (or anything similar)? What is done with the feedback (besides the data dump)? Does it change anything?

@W.O. Similar, but not a duplicate. I know I'm leaving feedback, I just want to how what the feedback does (if anything) and how it's tracked. The sole answer on that question said only that you're leaving feedback instead of voting (which I already knew). I also already knew that it was being recorded (as per a comment on the answer). The answer does not tell me if feedback changes how much the question is seen, or if anything is done with the feedback (besides the data dump).

Also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285181/622284 , which while the question title is barely related, the answers there are pretty spot on. It doesn't seem to do much other than be recorded in the 10k tools, in the data explorer, and the data dump. It's mainly an information tool for what users who can't vote voted on.
