# What does "your votes will change the publicly displayed post score." mean?

Tags: support, voting

I just tried to upvote and saw this:

[image]

```
Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will
change the publicly displayed post score.
```

I know that Stack Exchange keeps track of the votes from unregistered users - does it do the same for sub 15 rep users? And if so, do these votes go into another list or the same one as the unregistered votes.

Finally, I know that the unregistered votes list is not used for anything - is the sub 15 rep one used for any internal calculation (e.g. People reached)?

---

[The linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259583) answers most but not all of my questions - Is the sub 15 rep one used for any internal calculation (e.g. People reached)?