# Is sub 15 rep feedback used for internal calculations?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, post-feedback

[As Shog9 said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259591/):

> It means you're not voting. You're leaving "feedback" - we track the nature of your vote, but don't alter the post score in response to it.

If the post score isn't modified, is anything else being modified? Is this used for people reached or similar? Or is it just a tally?

Comment: I would assume it is used.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I would assume that it's not (unregistered isn't) and there aren't many places to use it.

Comment: It is recorded, but does not modify anything. I believe it does affect newsletters, i.e. questions with big feedback score might appear in newsletters, when otherwise they won't.