# How are downvotes without sufficient reputation recorded?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes

[image]
The popup above is a result of trying to downvote as a user with less than 125 reputation. The popup, in case you can't see it, states the following (emphasis mine):

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation **are recorded**, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

How are these downvotes recorded, and what do they do? Or rather, do they do anything at all?

The popup included is from trying to downvote a post on the [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/) site with only the Association Bonus.

Comment: You can find your answer here: [Did something change in the behavior of blocking users' votes if they don't have sufficient rep to vote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259583/did-something-change-in-the-behavior-of-blocking-users-votes-if-they-dont-have)