# What actually happens to recorded but not displayed votes?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, voting, privileges

When a user votes, but they have under the rep requirement.

Upvoting - less than 15rep; Downvoting under 125rep - ([*Besides Meta.SE*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down))

They get this message:

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are **recorded**, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.
>
> [image]

My question is, where exactly are they "recorded"?

What happens to them?

Comment: @PolyGeo, OP is asking about logged in, but not enough REP, which the proposed Dupe doesn't really address.

Comment: @StephenRauch You're right and I have retracted - I think this may be more useful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259583  If not a dupe, then I think it is something that the asker should review for and mention in their question.

Comment: @PolyGeo, Yes..., I don't have enough rep to vote, but I will flag...

Comment: Fun Fact - [Sudo isn't the only thing sent to Santa](https://xkcd.com/838) (fun-factor, and factyness not guaranteed. Warranty Void where Valid.)